# Grid filters for date not working on after and on filter

Tags: extjs

Am using Bryntum's Gantt and there are Dates column on it which is using date filer.
The Before filter works but the After and On filter wont work.They just give me no results.

In the below example you may see the values of `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

```
var data = [{
    "QuickbaseId": "439",
    "Id": "proj-439",
    "Name": "Allen- Rowland One",
    "StartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
    "EndDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "BaselineStartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
    "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-14T18:30:00.000Z",
    "PercentDone": "25%",
    "GanttLocked": "yes",
    "CheckedOutBy": "Chourishi, Mukta",
    "children": [{
        "Id": "cat-1368",
        "QuickbaseId": "1368",
        "VirtualId": "1368",
        "Name": "Clothing",
        "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Duration": "1",
        "BaselineStartDate": "",
        "BaselineEndDate": "",
        "PercentDone": "0%",
        "Rollup": true,
        "children": [{
            "Id": "subcat-2511",
            "QuickbaseId": "2511",
            "VirtualId": "2511",
            "Name": "Shirts",
            "ParentId": "1368",
            "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
            "Duration": "1",
            "BaselineStartDate": "",
            "BaselineEndDate": "",
            "PercentDone": "0%",
            "Rollup": true,
            "children": [{
                "Id": "task-5692",
                "QuickbaseId": "5692",
                "VirtualId": "5692",
                "Name": "My Party Wear",
                "ParentId": "439",
                "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                "Duration": "2",
                "BaselineStartDate": "",
                "BaselineEndDate": "",
                "ManualStartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualEndDate": "",
                "ManualDuration": "2",
                "ConstraintDate": "",
                "ManuallyScheduled": "no",
                "ConstraintType": "",
                "Rollup": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "TypeofTask": "Task",
                "ParentType": "SubCategory",
                "SortOrder": "0",
                "AssignedTo": "",
                "ActionDate": ""
            }],
            "expanded": true,
            "TypeofTask": "SubCategory",
            "ParentType": "Category",
            "SortOrder": "0"
        }],
        "TypeofTask": "Category",
        "SortOrder": "0",
        "ParentType": "Project",
        "expanded": true
    }, {
        "Id": "cat-606",
        "QuickbaseId": "606",
        "VirtualId": "606",
        "Name": "Electronics",
        "StartDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Duration": "0",
        "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-06T18:30:00.000Z",
        "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "PercentDone": "0%",
        "Rollup": true,
        "children": [{
            "Id": "subcat-903",
            "QuickbaseId": "903",
            "VirtualId": "903",
            "Name": "CellPhones",
            "ParentId": "606",
            "StartDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
            "Duration": "0",
            "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-06T18:30:00.000Z",
            "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
            "PercentDone": "0%",
            "Rollup": true,
            "children": [{
                "Id": "task-3046",
                "QuickbaseId": "3046",
                "VirtualId": "3046",
                "Name": "Repairing",
                "ParentId": "439",
                "StartDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
                "Duration": "0",
                "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-06T18:30:00.000Z",
                "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualStartDate": "2016-09-06T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualEndDate": "2016-09-15T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualDuration": "",
                "ConstraintDate": "",
                "ManuallyScheduled": "no",
                "ConstraintType": "",
                "Rollup": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "TypeofTask": "Task",
                "ParentType": "SubCategory",
                "SortOrder": "",
                "AssignedTo": "Chourishi, Mukta",
                "ActionDate": ""
            }],
            "expanded": true,
            "TypeofTask": "SubCategory",
            "ParentType": "Category",
            "SortOrder": ""
        }],
        "TypeofTask": "Category",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "ParentType": "Project",
        "expanded": true
    }, {
        "Id": "cat-672",
        "QuickbaseId": "672",
        "VirtualId": "672",
        "Name": "Food",
        "StartDate": "2016-09-13T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Duration": "0",
        "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-14T18:30:00.000Z",
        "PercentDone": "0%",
        "Rollup": true,
        "children": [{
            "Id": "subcat-992",
            "QuickbaseId": "992",
            "VirtualId": "992",
            "Name": "Beverages",
            "ParentId": "672",
            "StartDate": "2016-09-13T18:30:00.000Z",
            "Duration": "0",
            "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
            "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-14T18:30:00.000Z",
            "PercentDone": "0%",
            "Rollup": true,
            "children": [{
                "Id": "task-3160",
                "QuickbaseId": "3160",
                "VirtualId": "3160",
                "Name": "Tea & Coffee",
                "ParentId": "439",
                "StartDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
                "Duration": "1",
                "BaselineStartDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
                "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-14T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualStartDate": "2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualEndDate": "",
                "ManualDuration": "1",
                "ConstraintDate": "",
                "ManuallyScheduled": "yes",
                "ConstraintType": "",
                "Rollup": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "TypeofTask": "Task",
                "ParentType": "SubCategory",
                "SortOrder": "10",
                "AssignedTo": "",
                "ActionDate": ""
            }],
            "expanded": true,
            "TypeofTask": "SubCategory",
            "ParentType": "Category",
            "SortOrder": "9"
        }],
        "TypeofTask": "Category",
        "SortOrder": "8",
        "ParentType": "Project",
        "expanded": true
    }, {
        "Id": "cat-607",
        "QuickbaseId": "607",
        "VirtualId": "607",
        "Name": "Furniture",
        "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Duration": "0",
        "BaselineStartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
        "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "PercentDone": "100%",
        "Rollup": true,
        "children": [{
            "Id": "subcat-904",
            "QuickbaseId": "904",
            "VirtualId": "904",
            "Name": "Chairs",
            "ParentId": "607",
            "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
            "Duration": "0",
            "BaselineStartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
            "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
            "PercentDone": "100%",
            "Rollup": true,
            "children": [{
                "Id": "task-3047",
                "QuickbaseId": "3047",
                "VirtualId": "3047",
                "Name": "Assembling",
                "ParentId": "439",
                "StartDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                "Duration": "0",
                "BaselineStartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
                "BaselineEndDate": "2016-09-07T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualStartDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualEndDate": "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                "ManualDuration": "",
                "ConstraintDate": "",
                "ManuallyScheduled": "yes",
                "ConstraintType": "",
                "Rollup": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "TypeofTask": "Task",
                "ParentType": "SubCategory",
                "SortOrder": "",
                "AssignedTo": "",
                "ActionDate": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z"
            }],
            "expanded": true,
            "TypeofTask": "SubCategory",
            "ParentType": "Category",
            "SortOrder": ""
        }],
        "TypeofTask": "Category",
        "SortOrder": "",
        "ParentType": "Project",
        "expanded": true
    }],
    "expanded": true,
    "cls": "project",
    "iconCls": "projectIcon",
    "TypeofTask": "Project",
    "TaskType": "Gnt.examples.advanced.model.Project",
    "SortOrder": 1
}];
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

Comment: @Mukta can you explain little bit more. i have used Bryntum's Gantt in my previous application. may be i can help you